# I am trying to connect a local artifactory running on a laptop in docker to a remote artifactory on AWS behind an ELB

Tags: artifactory

I have set up Artifactory OSS Version 6.9.1 on an AWS instance behind an ELB and have been successfully deploying builds to it from GitLab CI/CD. I am now trying to set up a local Artifactory OSS Version 6.10.0  on my laptop so that I can develop builds locally before sharing with the team.

My local artifactory connects perfectly to JCentre and I can browse that repository.

My gradle build will happily connect to the AWS hosted artifactory at http://{URL}/artifactory and resolve my dependencies.

When I connect a remote repository with http://"{URL}/artifactory I get a 500 Internal Error message on Test. If I take off the /artifactory it says it has connected successfully but when I try to browse the remote repo it is empty.

I read [Connect one Artifactory to another Artifactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52414452/connect-one-artifactory-to-another-artifactory) and followed the instructions to edit the json configuration and make the remote repository a smart repository here https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Smart+Remote+Repositories.

It now has the smart repository image but still cannot be browsed.

Gradle still cannot resolve dependencies with the local artifactory using the remote-repo name.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the Smart Remote Repository documentation, you should configure the remote repository URL with the following structure:
http://ARTIFACTORY_URL/api/package-type/repository-key

So if you have a Gradle repository named "gradle-test", the URL should be:
http://ARTIFACTORY_URL/api/gradle/gradle-test

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In the end it turned out to be ridiculously simple. When setting up the remote repository the key needs to be in the url as well as the key field.

So for a repo with a repository key 'fractal' the connection URL is counter-intuitively http:///artifactory/fractal